# How to select all data from main table on bases of max record row data of its detail table

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have a table with 2 records and a detail table having multiple records linked with main table.

Records can be added or deleted.

What I want is to show all 2 records when current user role is not 18.

And when current user role is 18, show only 1 record from main table whose detail table max record linked with main record having userId 78.

this is my code:

```
$this->db->select('BaseTbl.*');
$this->db->from('table1 as BaseTbl');
if($this->roleId == '18'){
    $this->db->where('(select table2.userId from table2 where table2.masterId = BaseTbl.id ORDER BY table2.id DESC LIMIT 1)', '78');
}
```

I tried this so far:

```
$this->db->select('BaseTbl.*');
$this->db->from('table1 as BaseTbl');
$this->db->join('table2 as table2','table2.masterId = BaseTbl.id','left');
if($this->roleId == '18'){
    $this->db->where('table2.userId', $this->userId);
    $this->db->where('table2.id', 'max(id)');
}
```

Now showing that userId 78 record but not the latest one of that specific main table record.

Comment: What is it that you exactly want? Can you show what is the output you expect and what the output you're getting is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get my desired result using this.

```
$this->db->select('BaseTbl.*');
$this->db->from('table1 as BaseTbl');
$this->db->join('table2 as table2','table2.masterId = BaseTbl.id','left');
if($this->roleId == '18'){
    $this->db->where('table2.userId', $this->userId);
    $this->db->where('table2.id = (select max(table2.id) from table2 where masterId = BaseTbl.id)');
}
```